# String array looping out multipe text

Tags: java, arrays

In the same main, create an array of 10 strings.  Using nested loops, fill it with values so that each element is a string containing a number of x's based on the index, so the 0th element is "", the 1st element is "x" the 2nd element is "xx", and the 9th element is "xxxxxxxxx".  (hint, one loop will move you through the array, the other will add the right number of x's to the current element).

No idea how to do this....

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: it is the language java

Comment: take a look at my answer. And as a side note, for the future, post any attempt you have tried, because the most frustrating thing is to have to write something from scratch for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to start with the logic of the program

You need to start with the `main` method

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

Then you need to `define` an array of `String`s

```
String[] array = new String[10]; //creates an array of size ten
```

Next, you need to think about the loop. The first loop you need is the loop through the indexes and elements of the array. Using for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
```

This executes the contents within 10 times. Next you need to use a StringBuilder to append each 'x'

```
StringBuilder string =new StringBuilder();
```

Next you need to loop (using `for`) through the value of `i`

```
for(int x=0;x<i;x++)
```

Then append string

```
string.append("x");
```

After the 2nd for loop, populate the array at index `i`

```
array[i]= string.toString();
```

Then you are done! The variable `array` is what you need

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     String[] array = new String[10]; //creates an array of size ten
     for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
         StringBuilder string =new StringBuilder();
          for(int x=0;x<i;x++)
               string.append("x");
          array[i]= string.toString();
     }
 }
```

Without StringBuilder

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     String[] array = new String[10]; //creates an array of size ten
     for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
         String string ="";
          for(int x=0;x<i;x++)
               string += "x";
          array[i]= string;
     }
 }
```

Comment: so what does string.append and StringBuilder do? Is their a way to do this with out these and how do they work

Comment: @JonnieZuramski yes there is a way, but this way is much more efficient, because each time you do string += "x"; (the alternative) it creates a new string object every time. (It's much better practice to use StringBuilder

Comment: Could i see the other way? because this way doesn't really make much sense too me. If not its okay

Comment: @JonnieZuramski done :) if it works, make sure to accept the answer

Comment: Thank you so much! really cleared thing up for me, haven't got into the stringbuilder in my java book yet so don't really wanna skip around to avoid confusion but thank!!!